# Learning Inversion of Control through Dependency Injection in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject

Can someone please provide me a simple example of **DI and IoC**?
I understand the first one but was unable to get an implementation of the second one.

I'm working with *MVC 3* and I really want to use the [IDependencyResolver](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2011/02/01/IDependencyResolverAspNetMvc3.aspx), but I can't understand how.

Is [ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) an option or is it required?

Is there a tutorial like [nerdDinner](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/id-321793.html) and I wasn't able to find it?

Can somebody give me a link to study it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to grok real world DI and its patterns and anti-patterns quickly, I recommend getting [DI in .NET](http://www.manning.com/seemann/). (I've ordered it already EDIT: And it was a page turner that taught me a lot and should  teach people of all experience levels well)

Failing that, read all [Mark Seemann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126014/mark-seemann)'s [high-rated posts here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126014/mark-seemann?tab=answers#mark-seemann?tab=answers&sort=votes&_suid=132240971725808972456236944679%60).

I personally learned from the [ninject wiki](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki)<strike>, but that, while excellent, is Ninject 1.0 specific</strike>.

Comment: To anyone that look at this and search a simple example, please read [below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900398/learning-inversion-of-control-through-dependency-injection-in-mvc-3/4901434#4901434).

Comment: @Sam Holder: Going the whole hog on fanboyness, His [Zero friction blog series](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/01/28/ZeroFrictionTDD.aspx) and the AutoFixture library it has spawned are extremely insightful stuff too.

Answer (score 6):

don't use `IDependencyResolver`. It has nothing to do with Inversion of Control, and it's fundamentally broken. If you want to learn how to use IoC Container properly with MVC 3 see [this tutorial](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-tutorial-ASP-NET-MVC-3-application-To-be-Seen.ashx) (uses Windsor).

Answer (score 4):

This isn't my example, but is one I just ran across while looking for a simple, functional example.  It uses NInject and the final IoC functionality of .Net MVC 3.

http://www.shahnawazk.com/2010/12/dependency-injection-in-aspnet-mvc-3.html

Simple downloadable example project at the bottom of the article.

Comment: +1 a more direct answer than mine. Here's hoping the OP can, after managing 2 upvotes in 1 year and 9 months while asking 10 questions can add another +1 to this!

Comment: +1 great example. Thanks for reminding me the opportunity to up/down vote, I will use more often from now on.

Answer (score 0):

I cant answer for asp related techs, but on the academic side, the fact that you are using DI implies that you have inverted control.

Ill make it explicit -- when you do *not* invert control, you basically make the various components of an application resolve their own dependencies.  When you invert control, you allow the resolving of the dependencies happen at some other layer.  That is the 'inversion' of the control.